# preventing indenting to open paren when creating a new block in react-mode

Tags: indentation, spacemacs

I'm using spacemacs for react development.  i like it mostly but I have one issue that is annoying.  Currently emacs will try to align certain lines with the last opening paren, so something like this:

```
return React.createElement('div', 
                          { class = "className" }
```

I would rather the second line not be aligned with the opening paren and instead be indented only one extra 'tab' deep.  So something like this:

```
return React.createElement('div',
    { class = "className" }
```

I believe my problem is only if I'm stating a new block on the next line, ie I have an opening brace/bracket/paren as the first character on my second line.  For instance I get the indentation I expect if I do this:

```
return React.createElement('div', {
    class = "className",
    style = "whatever",
    ...
```

I'm not very experienced with eclipse configuration, I've stolen a mostly configured version for a peer so far.  I have tried following these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475279/how-to-control-indentation-after-an-open-parenthesis-in-emacs but they didn't change anything, presumably because I should be setting a different argument to control indentation for opening brackets, though I'm not sure what argument I need.

React-mode seems to use mostly default settings for indentation, I used standard-indent for instance to control indent size, so presumably it's using whatever the default settings are for controlling indentation as well.